# Error: object 'mle.result' not found

Tags: r

I wrote these R codes for simulation and estimation which are given below.

```
library(numDeriv)
library(Matrix)
library(LambertW)

alpha=3.5
beta=2.0
theta=0.5
lambda=4.0

n=50
#Generate a random variable from uniform distribution
u<-0
u=seq(0,0.99,0.01)

for (q in 1:n)
{
   x[q]<- (lambda/beta)*
    W((((beta/lambda^2)*log(1-theta*u[q]/(1-u[q]))*
          exp(beta/lambda)))^(1/alpha),branch = 0)
}

BXIIWG_LL <- function(par){
  -sum(log(par[1]*par[2]*x^(par[2]-1)*(1+x)+
   par[3]*par[2]*x^(par[2]-1))*(1-par[4])*(1+x^par[2])^(-par[3]-1)*
        exp(-par[1]*x^par[2])/(1-par[4]
         (1+x^par[2])^(-par[3])*exp(-par[1]*x^par[2]))^(2))

#Maximum likelihood estimation
mle.result <- nlminb(c(alpha,beta,theta,lambda),
    BXIIWG_LL,lower=0,upper=Inf)
```

The results I got are as follows:

> (1) Error: object 'mle.result' not found.
>   (2) warnings: In W((((beta/lambda^2) * log(1 - theta * u[q]/(1 - u[q])) : Some values of (((beta/lambda^2) * log(1 - theta * u[q]/(1 - u[q])) *
>    exp(beta/lambda)))^(1/alpha) are NA or NaN. Returning 'NA' for these entries.

How do I solve these problems?

Comment: when I run your code I get as far as the `for` loop before getting `Error: object 'x' not found`. Please edit your code to include a definition for `x` ...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the result in

```
  (((beta/lambda^2)*log(1-theta*u[q]/(1-u[q]))*
              exp(beta/lambda)))^(1/alpha)
```

For `q=2` you obtain `(-0.001043497)^ 0.2857143 =NaN`.. and I suppose this is the same also for `q>2`
is this what you really want?

Also.. Your function `BXIIWG_LL` uses `x`, but it doesn't receive `x` as an input.. Is this right?

Try this:
    library(numDeriv)
    library(Matrix)
    library(LambertW)
    library(pracma)

```
alphaDen=7
alphaNum=2
beta=2.0
theta=0.5
lambda=4.0

n=50
#Generate a random variable from uniform distribution
u<-0
u=seq(0,0.99,0.01)
x= c()

for (q in 1:n)
{
  numb =((beta/lambda^2)*log(1-theta*u[q]/(1-u[q]))*exp(beta/lambda))
  numbPow = numb^alphaNum
  sqrtNumb= nthroot(numbPow,alphaDen)
  x[q]<- (lambda/beta)*numb
    W(,branch = 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ale for detecting these errors. Please, how do I solve these errors?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are one in a million. Have a wonderful day Ale.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :D